# Running Forecast in Renjin

Tags: java, r, renjin

I need to execute some R scripts that process timeseries and perform forecast over them. I am using the [forecast](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast) package and everything works fine when executing the script from R console.

However, I always get the same exception when trying to do the same thing with Renjin: `Could not load package org.renjin.cran:colorspace`

It seems that there is some dependency missing so I am wondering, if there is some workaround for that.

This is the java/Renjin code (just loading forecast in this example) I am trying to execute:

```
private void testRenjin() throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("Renjin");

    // check if the engine has loaded correctly:
    if (engine == null) {
      log.debug("Error creating Renjin.");
    }

    engine.eval("library(forecast)");
  }
```

I have set the necessary dependencies in my **pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.renjin</groupId>
        <artifactId>renjin-script-engine</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0-RC7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
        <artifactId>forecast</artifactId>
        <version>4.04-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The forecast package includes C++ code which is not yet supported by Renjin. ([Issue #119](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/119))

You can always find the latest updates on package compatability on packages.renjin.org:

http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/forecast

Comment: The problem seems to be just the `color-space` package. Couldn't I just exclude it somehow? I was searching for this and it seems that this was an issue quite some time ago and has still not been solved. Does it mean that there is no hope to get the forecast working with Renjin at all?

Comment: We're working on support for C++ code, but in the meantime, you can always fork the forecast package and remove the dependencies and C++ code. I understand there are only one or two functions which depend on C/C++ code.

Comment: issue seems fixed at this time